# XSLT: Excluding child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, selector

We are using XSLT to transform XML into HTML.  In one portion of this we have a list of elements and we need to extract the string data, minus any XML markup, for use in another location.

The current XSL is simply:

```
<xsl:variable name="label_Text" select=".//column_header_1"/>
...
<xsl:value-of select="$label_Text"/>
```

This works fine in most cases, but some of the column_header elements contain certain child nodes that should be excluded.  Take this XML snippet for example:

> <column_header_1>
>       Foo <textstyle_bold>Bar</textstyle_bold> <editor_note>note from an editor</editor_note>
>   </column_header_1>

The current XSL returns "Foo Bar note from an editor" but we do not want the editor_note node included in this location.  The desired result from the above snippet would be "Foo Bar".

I feel like I should be able to use something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="$label_Text[not(editor_note)]"/>
```

but so far I have not been able to get that to work.

Note that the editor_note element should not be excluded from the entire document, it should only be excluded from this specific value, which seems to preclude using an empty  template to remove the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited/corrected version of answer from Bob Dalgleish:

Use a modal form of applying templates.

Within the column header, invoke `xsl:apply-templates` in a "non-editor-note" mode that suppresses such notes.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="non-editor-note"/>
```

There only needs to be one specific rule in "non-editor-note" mode:

```
  <xsl:template match="editor_note" mode="non-editor-note"/>
```

For all other nodes, the default template rules do exactly what you want: ignore markup and recurse down to the text nodes, then copy the text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a modal form of applying templates.

Within the column header, invoke `xsl:apply-templates` in a "non-editor-note" mode that suppresses such notes.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="non-editor-note"/>
```

Then set up some extractors that work only in "non-editor-note" mode:

```
  <xsl:template match="editor_note" mode="non-editor-note"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="non-editor-note">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

You may have to do some tweaking of the `value-of` element, but that should do almost all of what you want.

Comment: Almost there, but not quite: see my answer.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. My answer was overkill.